# OverFlowError: Python int too large to convert to C long on windows for CSV field size limit

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to set the field size limit on CSV

```
csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

This runs perfectly well on MacOS and Ubuntu but I am facing this exception on Windows. I am running `Windows 10 x64` and `python 2.7 x64`.

If I run the above line without arguments, I get the current limit:

```
csv.field_size_limit()
131072
```

How can I get this function to work on windows as well?

Comment: min(sys.maxsize, 2147483646) should work